# Почему работает new в шаблонной constexpr функции

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, constexpr

Есть шаблон функции, помеченный constexpr

```
template <class T>
constexpr auto foo() {
   return new int;
}
```

Вопрос: почему это работает? Стоить убрать шаблон и все (вполне закономерно, ведь new не может быть constexpr) перестает работать с ошибкой, что  new не может быть вычислено на этапе компиляции

Comment: Я нашел ответ на данную проблему [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56568230/constexpr-and-stdcout-working-on-function-but-not-in-lambda)

Answer (score 0):

Этот код не работает. `new` в `constexpr` разрешен только с С++20, и только при условии, что:

1. используется глобальная функция аллокации (тут соблюдено)
2. выделенная память освобождается там же (не соблюдено)

Comment: Если бы он не работал, я бы не спрашивал. Но его пропустили и clang, и gcc, msvc. Проблема в том, что constexpr становится здесь "ill - formed", но компиляторы не обязано это диагностировать